# Modeling AND of implication in integer/binary linear programming

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, integer-programming, constraints, binary-programming

## Problem statement

Let $\beta \in \{0, 1\}$ for brevity. A set of $K$ numbers $M_k$, represented as individual bits $B_{ik} \in β $, must be distributed to a set of $ J \le K$ pairs $F_j = (c_{ij} \in β , m_{ij} \in β)$ — please excuse the probably wrong notation, it's a pair of numbers $c$ and $m$ decomposed as bits — such that:

- $M_k$ must be distributed to **at least** one $F_j$
- if $M_k$ is distributed to $F_j$, then $(m_{ij} = 1) \implies (B_{ik} = c_{ij})$
- $\textrm{min}_j \sum_i m_{ij}$ is maximum

### "Degenerate" cases solutions

#### $J = 1$

> $c = \mathrm{AND_k}\ M_k$
>
> $m = c\ \mathrm{OR}\ (\mathrm{AND_k}\ \mathrm{NOT}(M_k))$

$\mathrm{AND}$, $\mathrm{OR}$, $\mathrm{NOT}$ are bitwise.

#### $J = K$

> $c_{ik} = B_{ik}$
>
> $m_{ik} = 1$

## A possible integer program

#### Auxiliary variables

$µ_{jk} \in β$: if $M_k$ is distributed to $F_j$.

$e_{ijk} \in β$: if $c_{ij}$ is constrained ($M_k$ is distributed to $F_j$ and $m_{ij} = 1$)

$s_{j} \in \mathbb{N}$: sum of $m_{ij}$

$s \in \mathbb{N}$: minimum sum of $s_{j}$

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{max}    &\quad s            \\
s.t.            &                   \\
 \sum_j  µ_{jk} &\ge 1              \\
µ_{jk} + m_{ij} &\le e_{ijk} + 1    \\
         µ_{jk} &\ge e_{ijk}        \\
         m_{ij} &\ge e_{ijk}        \\
         c_{ij} &\le m_{ij}         \\
B_{ik} - c_{ij} &\le \phantom{-(}1 -  e_{ijk}   \\
B_{ik} - c_{ij} &\ge -(1 -  e_{ijk})\\
           s_j  &=   \sum_i m_{ij}  \\
             s  &\le s_j            \\
\end{align*}

## Missing part

This formulation should be enough to get a feasible and (almost) optimal solution. "Almost" because the actually optimal solution also minimize $\mathrm{max}_k \sum_j µ_{jk}$, i.e. $M_k$ ought to be handled by the minimum number of F.

It's easy to check afterwards if $F_j$ handles $M_k$ (the test is $M_k\ \mathrm{AND}\ m_j = c_j$), but I'd like to have the corresponding $µ_{jk}$ set directly in the program.

However I was not able to come up with a linear set of constraints that can express

\begin{align*}
µ_{jk} = \mathrm{AND}_i\ ((m_{ij} = 1) \implies (B_{ik} = c_{ij}))
\end{align*}

i.e. if ALL the bits of $c_j$ for which the corresponding bits of $m_j$ are set to 1 are equal to the corresponding bits of $M_k$, then the latter is distributed to $F_j$ — it's the other way around w.r.t the constraints above (with the current formulation one can have e.g. $µ_{2,1} = 0$ even if $F_2$ actually handles $M_1$ too, just because the solution happened to map $M_1$ to $F_1$) — but the problem is that the constraint should work only in $F_j \longrightarrow M_k$ direction, without forcing $µ_{jk} = 0$.

Comment: Are $B_{ik}$ and $c_{ij}$ decision variables or input parameters?

Comment: @RobPratt $B_{ik}$ are input parameters, together with I, J and K dimensionalities, $c_{ij}$ are decision variables. I'll review the answer this evening, I come up with a solution in the meantime but yours seem to be both better and more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enforce the logical proposition
$$\mu_{jk} \iff \bigwedge_i (m_{ij} \implies (B_{ik} \iff c_{ij})) \tag1\label1$$

First rewrite part of the proposition in conjunctive normal form (CNF):
$$
m_{ij} \implies (B_{ik} \iff c_{ij}) \\
m_{ij} \implies ((B_{ik} \implies c_{ij}) \land (c_{ij} \implies B_{ik})) \\
\lnot m_{ij} \lor ((\lnot B_{ik} \lor c_{ij}) \land (\lnot c_{ij} \lor B_{ik})) \\
(\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot B_{ik} \lor c_{ij}) \land (\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot c_{ij} \lor B_{ik})
$$

Now rewrite the forward direction of \eqref{1} in CNF:
$$
\mu_{jk} \implies \bigwedge_i (m_{ij} \implies (B_{ik} \iff c_{ij})) \\
\lnot \mu_{jk} \lor \bigwedge_i \left((\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot B_{ik} \lor c_{ij}) \land (\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot c_{ij} \lor B_{ik})
\right) \\
\bigwedge_i \left((\lnot \mu_{jk} \lor \lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot B_{ik} \lor c_{ij}) \land (\lnot \mu_{jk} \lor \lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot c_{ij} \lor B_{ik})
\right),
$$
yielding linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1-\mu_{jk}) + (1-m_{ij}) + (1-B_{ik}) + c_{ij} \ge 1 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \\
(1-\mu_{jk}) + (1-m_{ij}) + (1-c_{ij}) + B_{ik} \ge 1 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$}
\end{align}
Equivalently,
\begin{align}
\mu_{jk} + m_{ij} + B_{ik} - c_{ij} \le 2 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \\
\mu_{jk} + m_{ij} + c_{ij} - B_{ik} \le 2 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$}
\end{align}

Now consider the backward direction of \eqref{1}:
$$
\bigwedge_i (m_{ij} \implies (B_{ik} \iff c_{ij})) \implies \mu_{jk}
$$
One approach is to rewrite as
\begin{align}
(m_{ij} \implies (B_{ik} \iff c_{ij})) &\implies f_{ijk} \tag2\label2 \\
\bigwedge_i f_{ijk} &\implies \mu_{jk} \tag3\label3 
\end{align}
Rewrite \eqref{2} in CNF:
$$
\lnot (m_{ij} \implies (B_{ik} \iff c_{ij})) \lor f_{ijk} \\
\lnot \left((\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot B_{ik} \lor c_{ij}) \land (\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot c_{ij} \lor B_{ik})\right) \lor f_{ijk} \\
\left(\lnot (\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot B_{ik} \lor c_{ij}) \lor \lnot (\lnot m_{ij} \lor \lnot c_{ij} \lor B_{ik})\right) \lor f_{ijk} \\
\left((m_{ij} \land B_{ik} \land \lnot c_{ij}) \lor (m_{ij} \land c_{ij} \land \lnot B_{ik})\right) \lor f_{ijk} \\
(m_{ij} \lor f_{ijk}) \land (B_{ik} \lor c_{ij} \lor f_{ijk}) \land (\lnot B_{ik} \lor \lnot c_{ij} \lor f_{ijk}),
$$
yielding linear constraints
\begin{align}
m_{ij} + f_{ijk} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \\
B_{ik} + c_{ij} + f_{ijk} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \\
(1-B_{ik}) + (1-c_{ij}) + f_{ijk} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $i,j,k$}
\end{align}
Finally, rewrite \eqref{3} in CNF:
$$
\lnot \bigwedge_i f_{ijk} \lor \mu_{jk} \\
\bigvee_i \lnot f_{ijk} \lor \mu_{jk},
$$
yielding linear constraints
$$\sum_i (1-f_{ijk}) + \mu_{jk} \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $j,k$}$$